# Why does Entity Framework always seem to dispose when doing async/await for adding entities

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, async-await

I am working on some APIs that hit other APIs, testing them, and then storing results in a Postgres. I've already completed other sections of it with using EF and async/await so the following code block is essentially a copy/paste..

```
    public async Task<OperationResponse> UpsertEvents(ILogger log, MCVPEvent eventToAdd, ICollection<MCVPEventStep> eventStepsToAdd)
    {
        int saveResult;
        long saveResultId;

        try
        {
            var eventDto = this.mapper.Map<MCVPEventDto>(eventToAdd);

            eventDto.MCVPEventSteps = this.mapper.Map<ICollection<MCVPEventStepDto>>(eventStepsToAdd);

            var addResult = await this.dbContext.MCVPEvents.AddAsync(eventDto);

            // this following line blows up-->        
            saveResult = await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            saveResultId = eventDto.Id;

            log.LogInformation($"SaveChangesAsync result: {saveResult} and id: {saveResultId}");
            return Operation.Success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"DbUpdateException: {ex.Message}");
            return Operation.Exception(ex);
        }
    }
```

but for the life of me I cannot figure out why the container keeps disposing of the context after I call Add... I've tried it with `AddAsync` and then `SaveChangesAsync`; I've tried it with just regular non-async `Add` and then `SaveChangesAsync`; it only seems to work when I use **both** of the non-async methods `Add` and `SaveChanges`.

Is it because I am calling other methods, like mapper or log during all this? Is it because my return values are not entities?

Comment: Without more context (including a proper [mcve]), there's no way to know which of the many async/await questions on Stack Overflow this is a duplicate. But it's nearly certain that there is one. I assume that by _"blows up"_ you mean that you find the `dbContext` object has been disposed. This would be because the caller of `UpsertEvents()` fails to keep the object alive, or disposes it prematurely. You need to _always_ remember when dealing with `await` that every `await` statement is a place where your method can _return_. Unless the caller understands that returning doesn't necessarily ...

Comment: ... mean the method is done, the caller will invariably go on to other things as if the operation was complete even though it wasn't.

Comment: 90% chance you forgot to await UpsertEvents . Only a [mcve] will get us to 100% confidence.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a long week.. heh 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to await the calling method, in my case UpsertEvents(..)!